# Difficulty or difficulties falling asleep

Tags: grammar

She had difficulty falling asleep and pulled the duvet over her face.
OR
She had difficulties falling asleep and pulled the duvet over her face.

Which sentence is correct and what is the Grammer to explain why that particular sentence is correct?

Comment: 'She had difficulty falling asleep' is a different way of saying 'She found it difficult to get to sleep'. A single if protracted problem. The usage is non-count rather than singular. 'We found difficulties in getting our applications accepted' stresses that there were multiple problems, though using 'difficulty' is by no means wrong here – it just gives less detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no question of grammar here. Both are completely grammatical.

However, one is idiomatic and the other is not.

You can use "had difficulty" whenever somebody tried to do something and found it hard - even if they encountered more than one problem.

If you say they "had difficulties", you are putting emphasis on the fact that there were several successive problems. It is likely that they were trying to do an action that required several separate steps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "difficulty" is the word. Difficulty in falling asleep refers to insomnia whereas difficulties could mean several other reasons for not being able to sleep.

Comment: Good answers explain why they a correct.